# How do i echo php for json string?

Tags: php

i need to echo $account into $url so that the url/path is whatever i get from $account plus the extension json. I can't figure it out with the quotes. i tried single and double quotes but no luck. any ideas?

```
<?php 
$account = $_POST['account'];
$url = 'echo $account.json'; //
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($content, true);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
<?php 
$account = $_POST['account'];
$url = $account. '.json'; //
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($content, true);
?>
```

the `.` operator is used for string concatenation in php.  This means take the value of `$account` and append the string `.json` to the end, and store that in the variable `$url`.  The rest of the code looks all right from there.  There are a few other ways to do this as well with strings in php, but I find this one simplest.

Comment: bloody hell mate. i had it in my mind i needed to type "echo" and that was causing the whole issue -- thanks a lot. it works now :)!!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as this

```
$account = $_POST['account'];
$content = file_get_contents($account.'.json');
$json = json_decode($content, true);
```

Need I remind you how, vulnerable your codes are to injection?

Answer (score -1):

The documentation on [`strings`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) goes into detail on how to format strings. You might want to try using curly braces (`{}`) around your variable as well to delineate where the identifier ends.

```
$url = "{$account}.json"
```